# Asterisk: SIP and IAX registration failed on remote connection

Tags: firewall, asterisk, cisco, voip, sip

I set up two asterisk servers (on Fedora) in different networks. My goal is to make a call from softphone (on windows lite with ip: 192.168.20.3) to the asterisk server 2 which is in the other network (ip:192.168.10.2). Actually the softphone on windows can register with asterisk 2 which is in the same network (ip:192.168.20.2). But the problem is in registration between the two asterisk servers.

> Architecture:

[image]

> IAX.conf in Asterisk server 1:

```
[general]
autokill=yes
register => zone1:welcome@192.168.20.2

[zone2]
type=friend
host=dynamic
trunk=yes
secret=welcome
context=incoming_zone2
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=192.168.20.2/255.255.255.0
```

> IAX.conf in Asterisk server 2:

```
[general]
autokill=yes
register => zone1:welcome@192.168.10.2

[zone1]
type=friend
host=dynamic
trunk=yes
secret=welcome
context=incoming_zone1
deny=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
permit=192.168.10.2/255.255.255.0
```

> extensions.conf in Asterisk server 1

```
[general]
autofallthrough=yes

[phones]
include => internal
include => remote

[internal]
exten => _5XXX,1,NoOp()
exten => _5XXX,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => _5XXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten => _5XXX,n,Hangup()

[remote]
exten => _6XXX,1,NoOp()
exten => _6XXX,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => _6XXX,n,Dial(IAX2/zone2/${EXTEN})
exten => _6XXX,n,Hangup()

[incoming_zone2]
include => internal
```

> extensions.conf in Asterisk server 2

```
[general]
autofallthrough=yes

[phones]
include => internal
include => remote

[internal]
exten => _6XXX,1,NoOp()
exten => _6XXX,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => _6XXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten => _6XXX,n,Hangup()

[remote]
exten => _5XXX,1,NoOp()
exten => _5XXX,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => _5XXX,n,Dial(IAX2/zone1/${EXTEN})
exten => _5XXX,n,Hangup()

[incoming_zone1]
include => internal
```

> Registration problem : Timeout

[image]

**NOTES:**

- PING between the two networks is ok
- There is no NAT
- Firewall on servers was turned off
- On routers, I create an ACL with 'PERMIT ANY' for each interface