# Asterisk and NAT: SIP and IAX registration failed on remote connection behind NAT

Tags: nat, asterisk, cisco, voip

I set up two asterisk servers (on Fedora) in different networks. My goal is to make a call from softphone (on windows lite with ip: 192.168.20.3) to the asterisk server 2 which is in the other network (ip:192.168.10.2).

But the problem is in registration between the two asterisk servers which are behind NAT.

NAT IP for Asterisk Server 1: 100.100.100.100
NAT IP for Asterisk Server 2: 200.200.200.200

> Architecture:

[image]

> IAX.conf in Asterisk server 1:

```
[general]
autokill=yes
externip=100.100.100.100
localnet=192.168.10.0/255.255.255.0
nat=yes
register => zone1:welcome@200.200.200.200

[zone2]
type=friend
host=200.200.200.200
trunk=yes
nat=yes
qualify=yes
secret=welcome
context=incoming_zone2
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
```

> IAX.conf in Asterisk server 2:

```
[general]
externip=200.200.200.200
localnet=192.168.20.0/255.255.255.0
nat=yes
autokill=yes
register => zone1:welcome@100.100.100.100

[zone1]
type=friend
host=100.100.100.100
trunk=yes
nat=yes
qualify=yes
secret=welcome
context=incoming_zone1
permit=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
```

> extensions.conf in Asterisk server 1

```
[general]
autofallthrough=yes

[phones]
include => internal
include => remote

[internal]
exten => _5XXX,1,NoOp()
exten => _5XXX,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => _5XXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten => _5XXX,n,Hangup()

[remote]
exten => _6XXX,1,NoOp()
exten => _6XXX,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => _6XXX,n,Dial(IAX2/zone2/${EXTEN})
exten => _6XXX,n,Hangup()

[incoming_zone2]
include => internal
```

> extensions.conf in Asterisk server 2

```
[general]
autofallthrough=yes

[phones]
include => internal
include => remote

[internal]
exten => _6XXX,1,NoOp()
exten => _6XXX,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => _6XXX,n,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN})
exten => _6XXX,n,Hangup()

[remote]
exten => _5XXX,1,NoOp()
exten => _5XXX,n,Playback(hello-world)
exten => _5XXX,n,Dial(IAX2/zone1/${EXTEN})
exten => _5XXX,n,Hangup()

[incoming_zone1]
include => internal
```

> Registration state: Rejected

[image]

**NOTES:**

- PING between the two networks is ok
- Firewall on servers was turned off

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asterisk: SIP and IAX registration failed on remote connection](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/355999/asterisk-sip-and-iax-registration-failed-on-remote-connection)